How to retrieve the resource class of an individual with the same data property in SPARQL
I’m currently working with an ontology using SPARQL and have defined two classes, both having the same data property named "name". I have an individual with the name "J.K. Rowling" and I want to retrieve the resource class of this individual.
However, when I run the following query, I end up getting results that include both classes associated with the name datatype property, rather than the specific class for the individual.
Here’s the query I used:
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX ex: <http://example.org/ontology#> 
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
SELECT ?class WHERE {
    <http://www.example.org/ebook#JKRowling> rdf:type ?class .
    FILTER (?class NOT IN (owl:NamedIndividual, rdfs:Resource, owl:Thing))
}

Despite this, I receive results for both classes instead of just the one that corresponds to "J.K. Rowling".
What’s the correct way to ensure that I only retrieve the class of the individual without including others that share the same name property? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
My Ontology file:
ebook.owl
View Graph:
webvowl

not that I understand why you want the URI back if you provide the URI, but here we go: SELECT ?ind WHERE { BIND( <http://www.example.org/ebook#JKRowling> AS ?ind)     ?ind rdf:type ?class .     FILTER (?class NOT IN (owl:NamedIndividual, rdfs:Resource, owl:Thing)) } - I also don't get the purpose of the filter.
